# 2,4GHz antennas are compatible with 5GHz connection?

Tags: wireless, antenna

I have a laptop that I would want to upgrade the wireless device with a new one that operates at 5GHz, and my question is if the antennas used for 5GHz connections are the same as for the 2.4GHz, or I'll have to change antennas with new ones.

Thank you very much!

> EDIT
>
> I'm refering to change first the wireless card from my laptop. My idea is to buy a mini PCI-e version of BCM94360HMB, named "AzureWave AW-CB160H", to update my older Realtek RTL8723BE.
> Like KalleMP said, I found that my laptop was distributed with dual bands adapters.
>
> I supose that my question is already answered, basically I want to know if the antennas for 2,4GHz and 5GHz bands are the same or not.
>
> Thanks for everyone!

Comment: They are not always the same, most antennas will have some kind of transmittance on both although your range may be reduced. The easiest thing to do would be to try it and see if it works. You probably are not going to find antennas the same size\shape and cable length to fit your laptop that are 5Ghz.

Comment: Many antennas are made to support both bands but if only made for one band they will have poor performance on the other. Check to see if your laptop ever came out with a 5GHz option, if so there is a chance that the antennas are dual band.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a laptop that I would want to upgrade the wireless device with
>   a new one that operates at 5GHz

Assuming that you mean that you want to upgrade/replace your "*wireless router*" and not the internal laptop electronics.

> my question is if the antennas used for 5GHz connections are the same
>   as for the 2.4GHz, or I'll have to change antennas with new ones.

The correct answer is: *it depends*

There are mono-band antennas, which are only for 1 band, and there are multi-band antennas which may do more than 1 band.

Usually, antennas on "*wireless devices*" are mono-band, and would only handle one band.

If you edit your question with more details and specifications of the equipment your are using now, and the equipment you are planning, then I will edit this answer with more precise info.

**[EDIT-based on edited question]**

You may want to check if your Laptop "allows" you to swap the Realtek out for another card. Many laptops have "white lists" in their BIOS, which may or may not be user configurable. I would advise you to double check this with the laptop manufacturer prior to buying anything.

Question is now on hold, so I will not be further updating this answer.

Comment: I want to change both of them, but in my question, I was refering to the internal mini PCI e module.